# Rails - How to capture attributes passed in to a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm passing an `rfid` value to a form to create a new `device` object.  How do I use that value to look through a list of existing `rfid`'s so the user may select one from `options_from_collection_for_select`?

Here's the code to pass the value:

```
<%= link_to "Create New Device (non-functional)", new_device_path({:rfids[0] => @rfid_id, cabinet_id: @cabinet.id}), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

And here's what I've got started for the code in the form:

```
<th>RFID</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field :rfids, options_from_collection_for_select(Rfid.all, "id", ) %></td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you using `options_from_collection_for_select` with a `text_field`? Is this form field supposed to be a select, or a text field?

Comment: You're right,  I will change that.    Either way I do not know how to retrieve the passed value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're passing a value as a parameter to `new_device_path`, and you want to use that value in constructing the form rendered by that action.

In order to do this, you're going to need to add some code to your action method (`DevicesController#new`, if you're using the Rails defaults. Otherwise, whatever action `new_device_path` points at). It'll probably use this general form:

```
def new
  @passed_value = params[:param_name]
end
```

All this does is store the passed value in an instance variable, but that means you'll be able to reference it in the form rendered by the action:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Rfid.all, :id, :id, @passed_value)
```